# How to initialize a tuple containing an list of expressions in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to create a method that recursively looks for a For-loop. I need to initialize the return value first (a tuple) but how do I do this exactly?
I've tried: tuple[list[Expression],Statement] = [];

Also, if I would bind a complete statement, like;

```
case s:\for(_,_,_,_):
```

would this be the correct type: tuple[list[Expression],Statement]?

```js
public tuple[list[Expression],Statement] showForLoops(loc project) {
 set[loc] files = javaFiles(project);
 set[Declaration] decls = createAstsFromFiles(files, false);
 tuple[list[Expression],Statement] result = [];
visit (decls) {
 case \for(initializers,_,_,body): result += < initializers, body>;
}
return(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plain answer is that you have to choose a `Statement` type like this:

```
result = <[], empty()>; // using the empty statement as a default
```

Note how I did not use a type (it can be inferred)

You could also write it with a type:

```
tuple[list[Expression],Statement] result = <[], empty()>;
```

There are other ways though to write this code, which you might find interesting.

The `\for` constructor itself, can replace the concept of the tuple you required. You can later project out its fields using `myForLoop.initializers` (for example):

```
Statement findFirstForStatement(loc project) {
    decls = createAstsFromFiles(files, false);
    visit(decls) {
       case f:\for(_,_,_,_): return f;
    }
    return empty();
}

rascal>ff = findFirstForStatement(pr);
Statement: for(....)
rascal>ff.initializers
list[Expression]: [...]
```

Or you can use a Maybe:

```
import util::Maybe;

Maybe[tuple[list[Expression], Statement]] findFirstForLoop(loc project) {
   decls = createAstsFromFiles(files, false);
   visit(decls) {
       case f:\for(_,_,_,_) : return just(f);
   }
   return nothing();
}
```

Or, finally, you might throw an exception if you can't find anything:

```
Statement findFirstForLoop(loc project) {
   decls = createAstsFromFiles(files, false);
   visit(decls) {
       case f:\for(_,_,_,_) : return f;
   }

   throw "couldn't find a for loop";
}
```

And a Bonus example collects all the for loops instead of finding the first:

```
list[Statement] getAllForLoops(loc project) {
   decls = createAstsFromFiles(files, false);
   result = [];

   visit(decls) {
       case f:\for(_,_,_,_) : result += [f];
   }
   return result;
}
```

Could also be written as a comprehension:

```
list[Statement] getAllForLoops(loc project) {
   decls = createAstsFromFiles(files, false);
   return [ f | /f:\for(_,_,_,_) := decls];
}
```